# Is it possible to override a validation ErrorMessage when you have a collection of the same model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

For example, if I have a 2 person objects as part of a View...

One is the parent and the other is the child, I don't want the error message to say "Gender is a required field" twice, rather have it say "Please provide child's gender", etc.

```
public class Person
{
   [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide a gender")]
   public char gender;
}
```

But then the other object:

```
public class ParentChild
{
   public Person parent;
   public Person child;
}
```

And in the view it's like

```
@HTML.EditorFor(model.parent.gender)

@HTML.EditorFor(model.child.gender)
```

Is there a way to do this with DataAnnotations or should I be just customizing the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not somewhere where I can try it, but yes, I believe you can do that. I think most (or all?) of the attributes in the DataAnnotations namespace contains an ErrorMessage property. So, you should be able to do something like this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide parent's gender")]
public char ParentGender { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide child's gender")]
public char ChildGender { get; set; }
```

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx) more information on the RequiredAttribute class and all of the properties you can set.

**Edit**: Based on the code that you added in your edit, I'd say no, I don't think what you are asking is supported with DataAnnotations. However, if you are using unobtrusive jQuery validation, a simple hack is to update the `data-val-required` attribute on your editor after the page is rendered with javascript. It would look something like:

```
$("#your-child-element")
    .attr("data-val-required", "Please provide child's gender");
```

You might also try setting it in the view but I'm not sure if the RequiredAttribute will override what you provide:

```
@HTML.EditorFor(model.child.gender, 
    new { data_val_required = "Please provide child's gender" })
```

Comment: @ioSamurai Ah, apologies for the misunderstanding. No, I'm not sure what you are looking for is supported - the DataAnnotation attributes are somewhat limited. I can't think of a reasonable solution to this without using javascript and the jQuery unobtrusive validation plugin. If you're using unobtrusive validation, then you could override the message in the data-val-required attribute on your editor. If you're validating server-side, you can adjust the error message on the ModelState object. Either way is kind of hackish.

Comment: @ioSamurai Another option would be to change the child object to an actual Child class so it could have it's own  validation message. But that could be a breaking change to your application.

Comment: Thanks, if you update your answer to briefly explain the data-val-required thing I'll give it to you.

Comment: @ioSamurai Thanks, I hope I was able to help.